# HOW (how) does Keras and Pytorch handle the last batch when batch_size is not a multiple of size of training data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, caffe, theano

Before you happen to suggest or report as duplicate, I am asking **HOW** does the two libraries handle the problem **NOT WHAT HAPPENS** because I know it can make a batch from remaining data. And I do know that it handles but all I am asking is **HOW**.

If I have 100 images as training data and `batch_size=15`, the last batch will have 10 images to train. My Question is that when the `Input()` layer already knows that the data is coming as a shape of `(Batch_size,channel,width,height)` for PyTorch and `(batch_size,width,height,channels)` for Keras using Tensorflow as backend.

If the last batch has size=10, isn't the model supposed to throw an error because it will get `(10,1,28,28)` in place of `(15,1,28,28)` given we have `(28,28)` pixels Grayscale images?

What is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: The batch dimension is variable sized (using None), so no, the network does not expect a given batch size.

Comment: But if we do ```F.cross_entropy(pred,labels)* batch_size``` won't it produce different value than expected because last one will have less images? we can ```reduction='sum`) in loss function but I am asking about the ```batch_size``` problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer) for example you can see that the batch size is optional. That is because the batch size is treated a variable in any iteration

Comment: So if that one is variable, ```F.cross_entropy(pred,labels)* batch_size``` won't it produce different value than expected because last one will have less images?

Comment: It would. But I don't see why you would multiply the cross entropy by the batch size, in general you want to divide by the batch size to remove that dependency, not multiply by it